# Looping though a text file and an Excel file

Tags: python, excel, file, loops, break

I want to see if a line from a file is contained (not equals to) a column from an Excel file.

```
data = pd.read_excel('C:/Users.../excel.xlsx', sep='\t')
f=open("list.txt", "r+")
for line in f:
    line = line.rstrip()
    for vh in data["Column_of_interest"]:
        vh = vh.rstrip()
        match = line in vh
        print (match)
        break
```

The results should be all 'True' but it only gives me 'True' for the first one.

Comment: You need a condition for break your loops, otherwise you always exit at the first line - first vh_element. When your loops should stop?

Comment: i want to compare everything, break and start from the beginning of the loop when a match is found, and continue to search for the next match.

Comment: for line in f:
    line = line.rstrip()    
    for vh in data["H_Sequence_File"]:
        vh = vh.rstrip()  
        if (line in vh): 
            print(line)
            break

Comment: Ok so you don't need `break` but `continue`. `break` just exit from all for loops, instead `continue` go to next elements of the first loop and restart the second for. I will post the solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're breaking even if you don't find a match... The code you posted compares all the lines in the text file with the first line of the Excel file, because it always executes "break" at the end of the first iteration of the inner for.

Comment: First of all, I would remove the "break" and check if the program prints all matches, even duplicate matches. Then, if you need to optimize it, I would add a condition like if (match) before the break, in order to break only if a match is found. Your code breaks even if a match is not found.

Answer (score 0):

```
data = pd.read_excel('C:/Users.../excel.xlsx', sep='\t')
f=open("list.txt", "r+")
for line in f:
    line = line.rstrip()
    for vh in data["Column_of_interest"]:
        vh = vh.rstrip()
        if line in vh:
            print True
            continue
```

Comment: everything else is what i got after i fixed the code except that i used 'break' instead of the 'continue' , it seemed to work.  'continue' and 'break' are different , which one should i use here?  thanks

Comment: i tested both, they gave me the same output, how is it so??

Comment: Looks like 'continue' is redundant in this case, and I don't see where match is defined

Comment: match is a simple True. `continue` permits to stop the iterations of the second loop and continue the first. `break` stops everything and exit from both for loops